# Grab mouse movement

Tags: ruby, qt, keyboard, mouse

I am writing a little utill for me on ruby using qt. How to access global mouse movement and keyboard input events?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to track mouse movement when no buttons are clicked, you'll want to turn on mouse tracking on the widget(s) you wish to track the mouse on. The function [`QWidget::setMouseTracking()`](http://doc.qtsoftware.com/4.5/qwidget.html#mouseTracking-prop), available on all `QWidget`s, will let you do this.

To capture mouse movements, you'll need to capture `QMouseMoveEvent`s. There are two ways to do this:

- If you are defining your own widget, then reimplement [`QWidget::mouseMoveEvent()`](http://doc.qtsoftware.com/4.5/qwidget.html#mouseMoveEvent).
- If you are using a stock widget, then you can create an event filter class and install an event filter on the widget you'd like to track mouse movements. See [`QObject::installEventFilter()`](http://doc.qtsoftware.com/4.5/qobject.html#installEventFilter).

For official Qt documentation, click the links on the functions of interest.

Answer (score 2):

Use [QWidget::grabMouse()](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.4/qwidget.html#grabMouse) and note that its a very **dangerous** function, use it with care.

Answer (score 0):

For mouse position, did you try [QCursor::pos()](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qcursor.html#pos) ?